# Is it possible to add new Item to dataSource variable list using jQuery auto complete text box?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, textbox

Here I am using jQuery autocomplete text box for sleet data from search box here when I type new item which is not exists in give `dataSource` list it's checks and if not exists I need to add data to `dataSource` list. How can I do this?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var dataSource = [
        { skill: 'ASP.NET'},
        { skill: 'C#.Net' },
        { skill: 'Sql Server' },
        { skill: 'Java' },
        { skill: 'AngularJS' },
        { skill: 'jQuery' },
        { skill: 'Javascript' }
    ];
    $('#basic').magicsearch({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        fields: ['skill'],
        id: 'skill',
        format: '%skill%',
        multiple: true,
        multiField: 'skill',
        multiStyle: {
            space: 5,
            width: 80
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use backend(php) to add new items permanently.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of a back-end language such as PHP or C#.NET ? Angular maybe ? What about SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to use either [html forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) or [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Your `dataSource` object will have to be persisted somewhere, probably in a database. The easiest way to do this as [Roland Ruul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4554704/roland-ruul) said would be to used a back-end language such as [php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/). You would then need to replace your hard-coded list with a json serialized object inject in your JavaScript code by the back-end language after it was retrieved from the database.

Considering your current setup, implementing this feature will be a lot of work